# Mixture of milk and hot chocolate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

[image]

In the picture we have cup of hot chocolate. Temperature and all values are given in the picture. Line pointing on grey part is the cup, brown is for the hot chocolate, line pointing on blue is milk and Luft forgot to delete is for the air. It is only hot chocolate, no milk.

Now we will add cold milk with temperature $T_M$ causing high to rise to $h_0=(1+\beta)h$. In this case, $β$ denotes the quantitative ratio between milk and hot beverage denotes the quantitative ratio between milk and hot beverage. The milk has the density $ρ$ and the specific heat capacity $c_{p, M}$ which are both constant and known. Assume that the two liquids mix instantly and homogeneously and that they do not react with each other (no enthalpy of mixing).

I should calculate specific heat capacity of this mix. There is similiar problem already but it doesnt help me that much. How should I calculate it?

[How make the perfect Hot Chocolate? Mixing liquids and temperature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309331/how-make-the-perfect-hot-chocolate-mixing-liquids-and-temperature)

Comment: If the heat of mixing is zero, the overall heat capacity is a mass average of the component heat capacities.